# How to send JSON in C# with DataContractJsonSerializer without charset?

Tags: c#, datacontractjsonserializer

I use `DataContractJsonSerializer` and `StringContent` to send JSON to a web service:

```
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Employee));
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
serializer.WriteObject(ms, employee);
ms.Position = 0;
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms);
StringContent jsonContent = new StringContent(sr.ReadToEnd(),
                               System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
// later I do HttpClient.PostAsync(uri, jsonContent)
```

This results in this Content-Type header:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

Is it possible to leave off the *charset* and just have the following header?

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

I don't see an overload on `StringContent` which does this.

Comment: If you do not specify encoding, which one server side should use: ASCII, UTF-8, UTF-16?

Comment: @Garath: if you don't specify the encoding or the media type, StringBuilder defaults to text/plain.  I need application/json. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158908.aspx

Comment: I know this. But you want to remove charset from reqest. Charset is same to encoding. If your request will be "Content-Type: application/json" how server should interpret it?

Comment: I misunderstood you.  I believe the server assumes the request is UTF-8, because that's what it sends back.

Comment: So why you want to delete this information from request? If you set it is much more clear

Comment: The API I'm talking to does not work when the charset is specified.  It only works when the charset is not there.

Answer (score 12):

When a new instance of the [StringContent class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.stringcontent(v=vs.118).aspx) is initialized via

```
public StringContent(
    string content,
    Encoding encoding,
    string mediaType
)
```

following HTTP request header for `Content Type` is generated:

```
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

> Pay attention to the presence of encoding part ( `charset=utf-8`)

In order to construct `Content Type` header *without encoding part*, the following options could be considered:

**1)** Using [StringContent Constructor (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158908(v=vs.118).aspx) and setting content type using [ContentType property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.httpcontentheaders.contenttype%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), for example:

```
var requestContent = new StringContent(jsonContent);                
requestContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
```

or

```
var requestContent = new StringContent(jsonContent);                
requestContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");
```

**2)** Remove encoding part from [ContentType property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.httpcontentheaders.contenttype%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), for example:

```
    var requestContent = new StringContent(jsonContent, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    requestContent.Headers.ContentType.CharSet = null;
```

**3)** Create custom [JsonMediaTypeFormatter Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formatting.jsonmediatypeformatter%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) that resets encoding part:

```
public class NoCharsetJsonMediaTypeFormatter : JsonMediaTypeFormatter
{
    public override void SetDefaultContentHeaders(Type type, System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpContentHeaders headers, System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType)
    {
        base.SetDefaultContentHeaders(type, headers, mediaType);
        headers.ContentType.CharSet = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I had been having the exact same problem, no matter what I set the charset to, it would always claim I was trying to use an "Unsupported Media Type".  I found that using this method of leaving the charset blank (as Slack was trying to do) solved my problem.  The trick is to specify the content type - which was absolutely required - later (I just did it on the next line):

```
StringContent content = new StringContent("Whatever=something");
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json");
```

(Please excuse the not-really-JSON formatting of the content, that isn't the point of my example.)